# Is there a way to access google.maps.LatLng from node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had this piece of code running fine when part of an html page. Upon triggering the search, it finds places of interest within a certain radius of the points passed in.

#### (index.html)

```
...
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={myapikey}&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>  
...
```

#### (script.js)

```
function googlePlaces(points) {
   points = [
    [2.627365, 49.215369],
    [2.760591, 49.647163],
    [2.952975, 50.057504],
    [3.344742, 50.280862],
    [3.768293, 50.451306],
    [4.21659, 50.534029]   // for sake of example
var i=0;
var placesOfInterest = [];
for (point of points){
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1],point[0])
  var request = {
    location: latLng,
    radius: '10000'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, 
    function(results,status){
        
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {  
        placesOfInterest.push(results);
        
        };
      
      
  }); 

  i++;  
  }
  return placesOfInterest;
  }
```

I now want to use this code within a node.js setup (no html) to return the placesOfInterest as a JSON. I've moved all of the relevant code into the 'controller.js' file of my API.

But now I get errors that 'google' is undefined.

#### What I've tried

So I tried importing the google libraries this way https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js, adding a line

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'myAPIkey'
});
```

and changing my `google` references to...

```
// service.nearbySearch(request, 
    googleMapsClient.nearbySearch(request,

//var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point[1],point[0])
var latLng = googleMapsClient.LatLng(point[1],point[0])
```

but I get an error that googleMapsClient.LatLng is not a function. How can I import the google libraries directly into my js file?

Comment: You want to load the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).  Your example code doesn't show you loading that, but you should get the error you report there as well.  You are probably loading it with the "loader" but that code isn't posted.

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes in my HTML version I am also importing the other API (edited now). However, the question remains as to how I can use this library within my API controller.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to mix the Node.js Client for Google Maps Services and Google Maps JavaScript API v3 code in one place. Please note that NodeJs client library for HTTP web services was designed for server side code and generally won't work with code from the client side Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

The NodeJs client library defines its own interface for LatLng described in

https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-js/docs/LatLng.html

> #### Interface: LatLng
>
> A latitude, longitude pair. The API methods accept either:
>
> - a two-item array of [latitude, longitude];
> - a comma-separated string;
> - an object with 'lat', 'lng' properties; or
> - an object with 'latitude', 'longitude' properties.

So in your NodeJs code you can do the following

`var latLng = [41.3848421,2.1841461];`

`var latLng = "41.3848421,2.1841461";`

`var latLng = {lat: 41.3848421, lng: 2.1841461};`

`var latLng = {latitude: 41.3848421, longitude: 2.1841461};`

and later pass this value to nearby search method.

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'myAPIkey'
});

googleMapsClient.placesNearby({
    location: latLng,
    radius: 10000,
    type: myType
}, function(err, response) {
    ....
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This has helped a lot, I am now seeing a valid response in my JSON. To remind myself, and leave some noob-friendly instructions, I was able to extract just the results by doing `if(!err){console.log(response.json.results);}` in my function